# Why is $\langle x| x' \rangle=\delta(x-x')$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I've tried to find any solution or proof for $$\langle x| x' \rangle=\delta(x-x'),$$ but I only came to this post: [Wave function and Dirac bra-ket notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55447/)

So I got the information, that the vector $|x\rangle$ form a dirac-normalized basis for the Hilbert Space.

I know that the dirac-delta distribution is defined like this:
$$\delta(x-x') = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x\neq x' \\
\infty & \mbox{if } x=x' \end{cases},$$ this means that my x' is a point on my x axis where I have my infinite high peak. And also $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\cdot \delta(x-x')=1.$$

But how actually correlate this with the scalar product of vectors x, x' in the Hilbert Space that form a so-called 'diracl-normailzed" basis of it?

Can you give me some tips on this please? Or maybe you actually know a link, where this is explained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between orthogonality and Kronecker delta function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55733/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89958/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273423/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Not an answer (the ones below are perfect), but a bit of a nit-pick. The $\delta$-function is not defined the way you say it is, but instead by the fact that
$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}y\,f(y)\delta(x-y)$$
For all well-behaved functions $f(x)$.
I know this feels a pit pedantic, but it's genuinely good to make sure you only use your definition as an intuitive starting point for understanding the distribution in physical contexts ($\delta$-function potentials or charges, for instance).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the "normalisation" of non-normalizable states chosen?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273423/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't it just from the [sifting property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiftingProperty.html)?

$$f(x) = \int\mathrm{d}x'\;f(x')\,\delta(x - x')$$

That is, if you accept the above and if you accept that

$$|\psi\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x'\,\psi(x')\,|x'\rangle$$

then

$$\psi(x) = \langle x|\psi\rangle = \langle x| \int \mathrm{d}x'\,\psi(x') \,|x'\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x'\,\psi(x')\,\langle x|x'\rangle$$

$$\Rightarrow \langle x|x'\rangle = \delta(x - x')$$

Comment: The  argument is not conclusive. This way you can only conclude that $\langle x| x'\rangle - \delta(x,x')$  produces $0$ when smeared with any function, not $\langle x| x'\rangle = \delta(x,x')$...

Comment: @ValterMoretti: This point interests me--could you elaborate?

Comment: There is not much to elaborate: from $\psi(x) = \int dx' \psi'(x) \langle x|x'\rangle$ and $\psi(x) = \int dx' \psi'(x) \delta(x-x')$  you get  $0 = \int \psi (x') (\langle x|x'\rangle - \delta(x-x'))$ for every $\psi$. Does it imply $\langle x|x'\rangle = \delta(x-x')$?

Comment: Without a precise definition of "delta function", a choice of the relevant class of functions and so on, it is difficult to develop any rigorous reasoning. What we can say is just that the formal manipulations of the symbols suggest that  $\langle x|x'\rangle = \delta(x-x')$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti: Because I am new to "ket" notation the elaboration is helpful and the point seems very clear.  Is there a modification of the argument that is conclusive?

Comment: Maybe it is enough at this level of formalism, after all this is the practical use of math in physics, not mathematics. As probably you know $\delta$ is not a function and the "definition" you wrote is inconsistent: If $\delta$ where a function, since $\{x_0\}$ has zero measure, you would obtain $\int \delta(x-x_0) dx=0$ even if $\delta(0) = \infty$.

Comment: To make conclusive this argument at this level of rigour it is enough to assume some sloppy axiom like this "$\int f(x) g(x) dx=0$ for all $g$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x$"...

Comment: (BTW I voted +1 Alfred Centauri's answer)

Comment: @ValterMoretti, your answers here are often above my level of understanding but I always enjoy reading them.   Thank you for your upvote.

Answer (score 1):

First, convince yourself that any finite-dimensional vector space, which you can easily think about in notation more familiar than bra-ket, $\sum_i \left|i\right\rangle\left\langle i\right|$ is the identity operator, where the sum is over elements $\left|i\right\rangle$ of some orthonormal basis. Indeed, $$\sum_i \left|i\right\rangle\left\langle i|j\right\rangle=\sum_i \left|i\right\rangle\delta_{ij}=\left|j\right\rangle$$proves the putative identity acts as expected on basis elements, and the general case then follows from linearity. All we needed was the orthonormality condition $\left\langle i|j\right\rangle=\delta_{ij}$.

Next we'll go to a space that is not only infinite-dimensional, but has a continuous spectrum of basis element labels. Our identity operator is now an integral instead of a sum, $\int dx\left|x\right\rangle\left\langle x\right|$. We want$$\left|x'\right\rangle=\int dx\left|x\right\rangle\left\langle x|x'\right\rangle,$$which is clearly true iff $\left|x\right\rangle\left\langle x|x'\right\rangle=\delta\left( x-x'\right)$.