# Continuous limit of discrete position basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, discrete, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

Say we have a $1D$ lattice with spacing $a$ between two sites.
How does one formally map the discrete position basis of the lattice to a continuous one in the limit $a\to 0$. 
For instance how does quantities such as $\lvert i\rangle$ with $i=xa$ maps to $\lvert x \rangle $? Or the orthogonality relations $\langle i \lvert j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ and $\langle x \lvert x'\rangle=\delta(x-x')$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89958/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273423/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330416/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

It was shown by the German mathematician Cantor that any mapping

$$ f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R $$

cannot be surjective, which means that there is no way to map a discrete infinite basis in a Hilbert space into a continuous one. This is rephrased as: a separable Hilbert space cannot be isomorphic to a nonseparable one. This means that there is a negative answer to all your questions.

Comment: But surely, physicists do take this kind of continuous limits all the time? Does it mean that any procedure of this kind lacks mathematical rigor?

Comment: Yes, those limits are mathematically ill-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think we can try to formalize it? Maybe embed $L^2(\mathbb N)$ into $L^2(\mathbb R)$ by having a constant value on each interval $[n \epsilon, (n+1)\epsilon)$. Then let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

We get a sequence of subspaces. A vector should be approximated increasingly well by its projection to each subspace as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.