# Orthonormality: from finite ($\delta_{ij}$) to infinite ($\delta(x-y)$) dimensional vector spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I've been reading [Shankar's book](https://books.google.co.za/books/about/Principles_of_Quantum_Mechanics.html?id=sDvrBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) on QM, but I'm unsatisfied with the section on "Generalization to Infinite Dimensions".

Given a finite dimensional vector space with a basis $\{x_i\}$, I understand that the basis is **orthonormal** if $\langle x_i|x_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ (where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta).

Extending this to continuous infinite dimensions, an example "basis" vector (whatever this really means in this case) may look like $|x\rangle$ where $x$ can be any real number in some interval. Apparently the basis vectors $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ are orthonormal if $\langle x|y\rangle = \delta(x-y)$, where $\delta(x-y)$ is the Dirac delta.

I would be convinced of this generalization if I could show the following:

- Define an inner product in the finite dimensional case with a basis satisfying the first orthonormality condition.
- Let the number of dimensions somehow go from finite to a continuous infinity.
- Show that in this limit basis still satisfies the second orthonormality condition.

Can the above be done, or is there a fundamental misconception I have here? Do you have any recommended reading? (preferably *not* an Analysis textbook)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89958/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273423/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330416/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic this is not a duplicate. Those other posts do not answer what OP asked. OP asked a more specific question about how the passage from finite to infinite works. There isn't a single summation symbol in any of the answers to the posts linked in your comment. Un-close this question.

Comment: To reopen this post (v3) consider to specify whether you mean finite, countable infinite, or uncountable infinite in various places.

Comment: Some details in the ADDENDUM therein : [Hermiticity of Momentum Operator (matrix) Represented in Position Basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280178/hermiticity-of-momentum-operator-matrix-represented-in-position-basis/423506#423506) may be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450526/2451