# Orthonormality and completeness in infinite dimensions: 2 different definitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

In finite dimensional vector spaces, orthonormality is defined as $\langle x_i|x_j \rangle=\delta_{ij}$ and the completeness relation is given simply by
$$I = \sum_i |x_i\rangle\langle x_i|.$$

To me, the most obvious extension of this finite dimensional case to infinite dimensions is to keep orthonormality as $\langle x|y \rangle=\delta_{xy}$ (where $x$, $y$ are real), while the completeness relation becomes
$$I = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i\rangle\langle x_i| = \int |x\rangle\langle x|.\qquad(\ast)$$

Now in quantum mechanics, orthonormality of basis vectors $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ in an infinite dimensional vector space is **usually** defined as $\langle x|y \rangle=\delta(x-y)$, while the completeness relation is given by
$$I = \int |x\rangle\langle x| dx.$$

It seems to me, however, that my extension of orthonormality and completeness to infinite dimensions is equivalent to the usual extension.

As a demonstration that my version of completeness is consistent with my definition of orthonormality, let $| f\rangle$ be some arbitrary linear combination (integral) of basis vectors $|x\rangle$:
$$|f\rangle = \int f(x) |x\rangle dx.$$
Applying my version of the completeness relation to it:
\begin{align}
\int |x\rangle\langle x|f\rangle &= \int |x\rangle\langle x|\left(\int f(y) |y\rangle dy\right)\\
&= \int\int f(y)|x\rangle\langle x|y\rangle dy\\
&= \int\int f(y)|x\rangle\delta_{xy} dy\\
&= \int f(y)|y\rangle dy\\
&= |f\rangle
\end{align}
so equation $(\ast)$ does work as the completeness relation.

Is there anything wrong with defining things this way? If not, then why is the usual definition of orthonormality and completeness preferred?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89958/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273423/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330416/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the main thing that goes wrong: What happens when you take an inner product?
$$\langle f|g\rangle = \int\int f^*(x)g(y)\delta_{xy} dx dy$$
You are doing a two dimensional integral over an integrand that vanishes everywhere except on the 1d subspace $x=y$, which is  a set of measure zero, so the integral vanishes. This is why we need delta functions to define scalar products when our states are written as an integral over a basis.

Comment: My argument is: let f(x) or g(x) simply be a Dirac delta (or proportional to one). Would my problem then be that my vector space is ill equipped to handle deltas instead of functions?

Comment: @Jean-Jacq, You will again run into problems when you take the norm of a wavefunction which is a sum of delta functions since the square of a delta function isn't defined. This isn't an essential problem though, you just treat it in a finite dimensional vector space (i.e. a spatial lattice). You are running into problems because you are trying to mix the two approaches

Comment: Good point. I think you've convinced me that my definition has too many problems to work.